# Meaning of 'visceral betrayal'

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-play

> Brazos: We are not looking for that here. No brown-nosing. No suck up.
>   No toolery.
>
> Brazos: Why is Shontel using what appears to be a red cup from the red
>   floor when we are on the yellow floor?
>
> Brazos' Aide: I'm on it.
>
> Brazos: It is a visual and, therefore, a **visceral betrayal**. Stop
>   it!
>
> -- [Transformers: Dark of the Moon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ee8E1I6vn5g) - Clip from Youtube

I know it's meant to be humorous, but I can't pinpoint the literal meaning of 'visceral betrayal.'

Comment: For the speaker, seeing is feeling.  That's about all we can say without straying off-topic.  The red against the yellow causes a visceral feeling.

Comment: Did you look up the meanings of *visceral* and *betrayal*?  If you google 'define visceral', one of the first results is "relating to deep inward feelings rather than to the intellect".

Comment: @stangdon It's a minor question. Dictionaries don't tell which sense applies in a particular context. I know what I'm asking.

Comment: For the record, when I posted my question I half-expected a comment like the one made by stangdon would appear. A good question would need to show some research. However, learners are in different levels of grasping English. You could not expect a junior learner just googles everything. For example, are you really sure the inquirer could understand what 'inward' and 'intellect' mean? Do you expect a non-native speaker can understand English better than a six-year-old native speaker? Then you'll realize dictionaries don't help much in many cases.

Comment: BTW, I have asked several native speakers before. They are not sure what's meant by it in the context. Perhaps stangdon is more educated than the rest of us.

Comment: @KinzleB - For what it's worth, you should take my comment in a positive light - your English is obviously very strong, so I expect more of you than I would of others!  :-)  More seriously, it would have helped if you had said, "I looked up *visceral* and *betrayal* in the dictionary, and I think the appropriate definition is _____"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A visceral betrayal is one you feel in your guts. However, I can't tell why the character says that here. In teenager talk: a betrayal that is a gut punch.

viscus, Latin for viscera, from which the adjective visceral comes.

Viscera: the internal organs in the main cavities of the body, especially those in the abdomen, e.g., the intestines. [usual definition in line with most dictionaries]

One could feel betrayed and feel it in the gut, or one can feel betrayed and feel it "in the heart" or head (intellectual betrayal).

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Lambie's answer.  The humor is in Brazos' *overreaction* to an extremely minor infraction, by calling it a *visceral betrayal*, something that makes him sick deep in his guts.  This, especially when contrasted with his previous statement that he wants, "No brown-nosing. No suck up. No toolery." when in fact it's clear he expects instant and inviolate obedience.

It's obvious the character is meant to be a dictatorial little tyrant who has no idea of what he actually is. With this kind of role John Malkovitch is well known (and expected) to [chew the scenery](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chew_the_scenery) with great enthusiasm.